# How to filter aws resource in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a cloudformation template with a parameter like this

```
Subnet:
  Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id'
```

this gives me a dropdown of subnets. I would like to filter them out so that only those with a label containing a certain string show up in the dropdown.

Is there a way of specifying this using maybe `AllowedValues`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to filter them out

Sadly there is no such possibility. You have to go through entire list or hardcode few subnets in  `AllowedValues`.